# Paging in Angular Js to redirect to same page without going to first page

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a situation in paging like, i bought all the data from **$http request** at a time(for example 50 records) and there i used following for paging.

```
$scope.numPerPage = 10;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;

<pagination total-items="game-length" page="currentPage"
 max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" 
boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages">
</pagination>
```

Records are now divided into 10-10. Now from third page i clicked on first record, i'm redirecting to another html page to show that particular records data. Now i'm coming back then  my page is reloading completely and starting from the first page. I'm trying to get back to third page itself. Please give me any solution. Thank you

Comment: it will reload from first page, what you can do is have a route or state parameter which tells the controller which page you want, you can also make it optional; then, if you get that parameter set $scope.currentPage to that.

Comment: You could add the last active page to the browser local storage and then check for it each time this route is activated

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state of the current pagination page before going to the next page in the `localStorage` or any `factory/value`(if not reloading it completely) and before coming back check the previous state of the page and initialize it.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z5nnAwSUQonk3qw6SUTj) to change page for pagination.

Comment: Yes, i'm using cookies to store current page value after that i'm sending to other page, so that i can overwrite current page with cookies value and  i'm getting data(for ex from page 3 i redirected to other and came back with the value '3' from cookie) so the data from 20 to 30 records are coming in first page only, actually i need to show those records in page number 3 and first page number should have 0 to 10 records and second page number should have 10 to 20 records and third should have 20 to 30 records. 
  Actually $scope.watch(currentPage) function not able to identify

Comment: Can you provide a plunker for this? So I would debug it.

Comment: Here is Plunker to give you some information
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5hNrFQWspREEkZgkGFk?p=catalogue

Comment: @VamsiPerivilli It is not working. Please provide a working plunker with some mock data instead.

Comment: Actually i'm getting all the data from server, to make it run i need to get from service and it is huge data

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, set a 'GET param in your url like this:

```
xxx.com/yourpage?pageNum=@pageNum&yourOtherParams
```

In your `ng-init` function:

```
$scope.currentPage = $location.search()['pageNum'] ? $location.search()['pageNUm']:1;
// do other things you need
```

In your pageChange Event:

```
$location.search({pageNum:$scope.currentPage+1});
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thank you and once i will apply this.